# How to improve HDF5 I/O(write file) efficiency?

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I have very much time-related scientific data to write, means data should be written into hdf5 file every several seconds. My hdf5 file structure is designed below:

1. create many time group, like time-1-group, time-2-group, time-3-group, and etc...
2. In time group, many dataset are created, like DataSetA, DataSetB, DataSetC, and etc...
3. Write data into dataset above.

API used: **HDF5-Fortran**

Run this program, everything is ok, but speed is slow, How to improve hdf5 write action efficiency? Thank you very much.

Comment: Speed is slow ?  1B/s slow or 10GB/s slow ?  What fraction of your file system's maximum write rate are you getting ?  Do you have a parallel file system ?  Is your code parallelised in any way ?  What does your program do in the way of write-buffering before calling HDF5 write routines ? So many questions, so little data ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Hi, i do not use parallel API, just use h5ltmake_dataset_int() API. Most of scientific data are two-dimenstional real data array.

Comment: I tend to agree with @HighPerformanceMark - I/O is always slow.  This output is slow compared to what?  How much slower is the HDF5 output compared to say just writing the arrays as unformatted fortran binaries? (not as a recommmended file I/O strategy, just as a simple benchmark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are fragmenting your data into groups for each time step (I'm just guessing from what you wrote). It may be more efficient to add an additional dimension to all of your datasets which would represent the time step and get rid of the groups because you could buffer a bunch of iterations together before each write.

In clear, instead of:

```
/time-1-group
    /time-1-group/DataSetA -> 2d array
    /time-1-group/DataSetB -> 2d array
    ...
/time-2-group
    /time-2-group/DataSetA -> 2d array
    /time-2-group/DataSetB -> 2d array
    ...
...
```

you would have this:

```
/DataSetA -> 3d array where third index is time
/DataSetB -> 3d array where third index is time
...
```

You would have to use chunked datasets and select the chunk size with care to optimize I/O efficiency (and as I said above you could have more than one time step per chunk).

Comment: Hi, Simon. Thanks very much for your tips and very clear illustration. But I am confused with **"get rid of the groups because you could buffer a bunch of iterations together before each write"**, could you show me an example. Thank you!

Comment: I gave the example when I said “In clear, …”. Right now you seem to have groups (`time-1-group`, `time-2-group`…) inside the root group (`/`), and datasets (`DataSetA`, `DataSetB`…) inside each of these groups. I recommend you write your datasets directly in the root group, and that you add a dimension to each dataset whose index would be the time step.

Comment: To understand the *buffer* and *chunk* part, you should learn how hdf5 works, and not just the high-level interface. You will also need to use *hyperslabs*. The [HDF5 documentation](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/) is great.

Comment: @Simon - "The HDF5 documentation is great" - your comment may be the first time that this sentence has appeared [anywhere on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+hdf5+documentation+is+great%22).